# Postgresql jsonb -> invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "mt"

Tags: node.js, postgresql, psql, pg

So I'm trying to inner join multiple tables in order to bind jsonb with a name. But I'm getting this error.

> ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "mt"

Find the recreational fiddle of the problem below.

```sql
SELECT test,jsonb_build_object(
    'myData_updated',
    json_agg(elems || jsonb_build_object('product_name', po.name))
)

FROM mainTable mt,
jsonb_array_elements(mt.myData) AS heading_elems,
jsonb_array_elements(heading_elems -> 'pItems') AS elems

JOIN products po ON (elems ->> 'pid' )::int = po.pid

INNER JOIN clients client ON client.client_id = mt.client_id
INNER JOIN projects project on project.project_id = mt.project_id
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=63e5b8a49940bb50b5bb7985a947c09e

I have tried removing alias i still get the same error. Quick googling says it is caused because of JOIN & "**, delimited FROM**" query

Comment: Don't mix implicit joins an explicit joins

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Is there a rule for when it's working? Because in this case (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=c200a5cecba2f792e1f3dadbe762e731) the implicit syntax has been chosen, followed by an INNER JOIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax

```
table,
json_array_elements()
```

is the shortcut for

```
table CROSS JOIN LATERAL
json_array_elements()
```

So with the `,` syntax you used is an implicit join. After that, with using INNER JOIN you are using an explicit join. The mix is not always working, so replace the implicit syntax with an explicit one and it works.

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=aaf2f78058714249522bed3a52affb66)

---

Beside this, the used function `json_agg()` is an aggregate, so if you want to get other columns like test you have to do a `GROUP BY` and/or use more aggregate functions on these columns.

Comment: actually the comma join syntax without `WHERE` to be defined as `CROSS JOIN` not `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` in the SQL standards..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Not in case you join set returning functions: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/241369/understanding-joined-set-returning-functions-in-the-from-list

Comment: Yes i see what you mean.. The keyword LATERAL is implicitly added with set returning functions like `json_array_elements()`.. Also meaning the LATERAL keyword in this case is "optional"  -> as it does not matter if you write `table CROSS JOIN
json_array_elements()` (where mine first comment was about more or less) or `table CROSS JOIN LATERAL
json_array_elements()` -> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=64141a8715176cf060d4dc544599d9ec ..